# is there any c program API to synchronize the system clock to ntp server?

Tags: c

I'm making a C library software that needs to synchronize system clock with remote NTP server. For now, I'm using "system" command to call the console "ntpdate id.pool.ntp.org" command.

so using of "system" is not proper so there is any other way do the synchronize the clock please help me.

Comment: The [Network Time Protocol RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5905) is a public document that describes its workings...

Comment: What about libntp https://github.com/ntpsec/ntpsec/tree/master/libntp

Answer (score 0):

**No:** The C standard library knows nothing about NTP.

**Yes:** There are libraries that implement what you want. However, software recommendations are out of scope of StackOverflow. You need to look for them yourself. A good web search tool is your friend.